# What does a proper etag response look like?

Tags: http-status-codes

We were wondering,

Header wise... What does a proper etag response look like.

Etag response, in the sense that an e-tagged request is made, and yes it matches the etag on our end, thus no content must be sent.

Does it need to contain a content-length header?

Do we use a 304 header response?

---

**Claritifaction:**

We want to etag handle via php.

The flow is as follows:

a) Etagged request comes in.

b) PHP checks the etag to see if it meets what we think is a proper condition **NOT** to send back a full document body.

c) What do we manually send back via php to signal to the browser to use the cached content?

Thanks!

Comment: `ETag` is not a response, but a header that uniquely identifies the resource contained in the response. [Wikipedia describes ETag usage](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_ETag) quite well.

Comment: Perhaps I was unclear in my question, I will revise it to be more clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answered my own question after reading the wiki as lanzz sudgested in the comment above:

> "In this subsequent request, the server may now compare the client's
>   ETag with the ETag for the current version of the resource. If the
>   ETag values match, meaning that the resource has not changed, then the
>   server may send back a very short response with an HTTP 304 Not
>   Modified status. The 304 status tells the client that its cached
>   version is still good and that it should use that."

So yes, a 304 response is the correct way to answer an etagged request if you want the user agent to use the cached copy.